# Is it a bad idea to keep class implementations in a static field of its interface?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, factory-method

I'm working on a project where we keep actual class implementations in a static field of the interface. One example of this is :

```
public interface Storage {

  public static Storage instance = new DiskStorage();

  public File get(String name) throws Exception;

  public void create(File f) throws Exception;

  public void delete(File f) throws Exception;

}
```

We do this keep avoid the complexity of using IoC frameworks, and to avoid littering our code with calls like `context.getImpl(Storage.class)`. Furthermore, we also do this in an attempt to avoid introducing large factory classes which we believe we can do just as well by keeping an implementation reference in a static field of the interface. What we achieve with this is that any part of the application which needs to store something just do that with `Storage.instance.create(File f)`.

However, we've been discussing if this is going against widely accepted "principles". First of all; are we into trouble for creating an implementation dependency in the interface? Strictly speaking, the interface now has a direct "reference" to the implementation. Second, we realize that our tests can not just "inject" a `MemoryDiskStorage` or a `MockDiskStorage` as a static field in an interface is a final field. How do we get around this?

Comment: "public static" is not necessary because Fields in interfaces are automatically public static final, and methods are public abstract.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you've answered your own question: Yes, it's a bad idea, because by working around the complexity of IoC, you've broken IoC and made it impossible to mock the storage implementation in your tests. There's a *reason* for those `context.getImpl(Storage.class)` calls.

Answer (score 1):

It makes you unable to separate your interface from implementation.

E.g., in a more complex application with `ModuleA` depending on `ModuleB`, you may want to separate interfaces of services in `ModuleB` into `ModuleBInterface` so that `ModuleA` only depends on `ModuleBInterface`. Your approach makes this impossible, because the interface depends on implementation as well as the implementation depends on its interface.